# flotchart: change cursors

Tags: css, cursor, jquery, flot

I would like to change cursor style under a scatterplot using http://www.flotcharts.org/

For example, I would like to change the cursor to a crosshair when selecting a selection to zoom, etc. or change the cursor to a pointer when displaying atooltip.

I have tried JQuery CSS modifiers such as placeholder.css('cursor', 'pointer');
but have had no success.
Any idea ?

thanks
giorgio

Comment: solution is simply as:

    $("#placeholder").css('cursor', 'crosshair'); 

sorry for my initial question (my ignorance on CSS)